# In Shiny, why is eventReactive running on startup before UI elements are interacted with

Tags: shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have this code, I want users to type in a product and a search term and then press a search button.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

  filtered_df <- eventReactive(
    {
      input$do_search
      input$search_tolerance
    }, 
    {
      enable("search_results")
      print("Performing search...filtering results and calculating match")
      
      if(is.null(input$ingredients)) {  
        filtered_df <- calculate_match_score(cases_df, input$search_term) %>% filter(match_score <= input$search_tolerance)
        #filtered_df <- filtered_df[order(-lv_distance, primary_suspect_key_ingredient),]
      } else {
        
        filtered_df <- calculate_match_score(filter(cases_df, PRIMARY_SUSPECT_KEY_INGREDIENT %in% input$ingredients), input$search_term) %>% filter(match_score <= input$search_tolerance)  
        #filtered_df <- filtered_df[order(-lv_distance, primary_suspect_key_ingredient),]
      }
    }
  )
  
  output$search_results <- renderDataTable(filtered_df())
  

}
```

The issue is, it is running on startup, not when I expect it will run - i.e. when the do_search button is pressed for the first time, or the search_tolerance slider has been adjusted by the user for the first time.

Comment: Try the option `ignoreInit = TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ignoreNULL = FALSE`.

> Both observeEvent and eventReactive take an ignoreNULL parameter that affects behavior when the eventExpr evaluates to NULL (or in the special case of an actionButton, 0).